# Oracle SQL, return unique (max) row in subquery in SELECT header (before FROM, WHERE)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am running SQL through Business Objects on an Oracle server. I have the following code (simplified), which sometimes runs:

```
SELECT
  a.col1,
  a.col2,
  a.date1,
    (
    SELECT
      b.date2
    FROM
      tbl b
    WHERE
      b.ID = a.ID
      AND
      b.date2 >= a.date1-60
    ) AS SUBDATE
FROM
  tbl a
WHERE
  a.col1 = 'foo'
  AND
  a.col2 = 'bar'
  AND
  a.date1 = '#somedate#'
```

So as you see, there is a subquery in the SELECT clause, which I want to return a single value: b.date2. This does work... some of the time. However, if b.ID returns **more than one** record where date2 is within the last 60 days of date1, then the query fails.

What I want to do is to limit the subquery's output to the single most recent value of date2. I have tried all sorts of things: MAX, LIMIT 1, DISTINCT... however the SQL will not compile, telling me that I have errors. For example the following **TOP 1** produces an error saying "FROM keyword not found where expected":

```
    (
    SELECT
      TOP 1 b.date2
    FROM
      tbl b
    WHERE
      b.ID = a.ID
      AND
      b.date2 >= a.date1-60
    ) AS SUBDATE
```

The following **ORDER BY/LIMIT** produces an error saying "Missing right parenthesis":

```
    (
    SELECT
      b.date2
    FROM
      tbl b
    WHERE
      b.ID = a.ID
      AND
      b.date2 >= a.date1-60
      ORDER BY b.date2 LIMIT 1
    ) AS SUBDATE
```

(Reproduced subqueries only above).

From researching these errors, I see various advice about subqueries **after** the main WHERE clause; however nothing about subqueries in the way I want to use them.

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting errors, and what the correct way should be do do what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find `TOP 1` or `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: `SELECT
      MAX(b.date2)
    FROM` should work. And you might be able to replace it with a `MAX OVER` or `LAG OVER`...

Comment: dnoeth - yes, thank you! I has tried the Max() outside the whole SELECT subquery, but didn't try it inside :)
Horse: to be honest I don't have an Oracle manual - it never occurred to me that Oracle could have a form of SQL so different to anything else that standard commands such as TOP & LIMIT might not be included.

Comment: Both `TOP` and `LIMIT` are not Standard SQL :-)

Comment: dnoeth - news to me! Thank you. As an SQL n00b I have to learn through experimentation & failure, and looking things up online. There's a lot of documentation out there, but it was not yet made explicit to me what is or isn't "standard" SQL (I didn't even know there was more than one variety until recently). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle can be a pain in this case (unless you are using Oracle 12).  One method uses `keep`.  However, in your case `max()` is sufficient:

```
SELECT . . . 
     (SELECT MAX(b.date2)
      FROM tbl b
      WHERE b.ID = a.ID AND
            b.date2 >= a.date1 - 60
     ) AS SUBDATE
. . .
```

Note:  You don't need the condition on `date2` in the subquery, unless you really want to limit results to the last 60 days.

Comment: I really don't see why you can't use MAX here... +1 from me. :)